# Who says /ˈjumə/ for "humor"?

Tags: nouns, pronunciation, dialects, rhoticity

What dialect(s) pronounce *humor* voiced initially and non-rhotic finally (i.e., with both those features in the same dialect: the word would be pronounced something like `/ˈjumə/`)?

Comment: What, you mean besides [Californians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuma,_Arizona)? :)

Comment: A gentleman trav'ling through Yuma / Told an elephant joke to a puma. / Now his bones bleaching lie / Under cold Western sky / For the puma had no sense of humor.

Answer (score 8):

[New Yorkers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_dialect)

Non-rhotic dialect? Yes. Dropping /h/ from /hju/-initial words? Yes. It's not just "something like" /ˈjumə/; that is the stereotypical New York City pronunciation of *humor*.

Comment: +1. But I'm looking for a complete list, or complete to the extent feasible.

Comment: @msh210: It'll happen virtually everywhere, with greater or lesser prevalence. And it'll be used across a spectrum of completely facetious thru slightly self-conscious to totally natural. It's just an almost inevitable consequence of dropping the /h/ for many "lazy speakers".

Comment: I am fairly sure that New York City is the only place where people do this systematically in the U.S., as opposed to occasional "laziness", as FumbleFingers comments. Many New Yorkers ***never*** pronounce the 'h' in "human", "humor", "huge", and so on, although they pronounce 'h's in other words. I don't know much about British or Australian dialects, so I can't provide you a list there, but there is a lot more h-dropping on that side of the pond.

Comment: @PeterShor fyi "Non-rhoticity is featured in many accents in England, Australia, and the North Eastern region of the USA, among others." [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents) - now just unclear how they handle the 'h' and we've almost a list

Comment: @PeterShor [h-dropping](https://notendur.hi.is/peturk/KENNSLA/87/VARS/H%20Droppinghtml.html) in England  and "Beyond England, h-dropping accents tend to be found in newer colonies, such as Australia and New Zealand." - [The Englishness of H-Dropping](http://dialectblog.com/2012/06/02/the-englishness-of-h-dropping/)